# scala and akka on linux: compiling and executing

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I'm trying to run a scala/akka based program on a linux cluster machine. I was following the tutorial link (this was the only example I could find):
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html

It says to use the command to obtain the akka library:
git clone git://github.com/akka/akka.git

But it doesn't have any jars files inside it as per the tutorial.

I'm not able to get a basic akka-scala-sbt combo working on linux. So any help on this is much appreciated. I'm not aware (not able to find any clear source) of the commands needed to compile/execute with and without using SBT.

Java version: "1.8.0_31"
Scala version: "2.11.5"
Akka: I'm not sure, I did git clone, believe its the latest
SBT: 0.13.9

Java,Scala are already installed on the cluster, I had to just use module load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this simple example: https://github.com/izmailoff/SmallAkkaProjectExample. It will help you to understand how to compile and run a project.

Usually the steps are:

1. Start SBT
2. Compile code
3. Run it from SBT

or:

1. Start SBT
2. Compile executable JAR
3. Run the JAR from command line

If you want a more advanced example take a look at: https://github.com/izmailoff/remote-akka-server-template

In either of these projects you don't need to download any libraries/JARs. SBT will download everything you need automatically.

In short, you need to understand how to build projects with SBT and how to run them - not related to Akka. Separately from that you need to know how Akka runs, i.e. ActorSystem, kernel, etc.